# Node JS post request giving 400 whereas from Postman it works

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

I am new to working with nodejs and have run into this seemingly trivial issue where the node JS code pasted below comes up with a 400 for the POST call I am trying to make:

```
jsonObjectJira = JSON.stringify({
      "XXXXXX": {
            "id": "XXX"
          }
        });

console.log(jsonObjectJira);

//prepare the header for the JIRA request
var postheadersjira = {
 'authorization' : 'XXXXXX',
 'cache-control' : 'no-cache',
 'content-type' : 'application/json',
};

//the post options
var optionspostjira = {
 host : 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX',
 port : XXXX,
 path : 'rest/api/2/issue/XXXXX/transitions',
 method : 'POST',
 headers : postheadersjira
};

//do the PUT call
var reqPostJira = http.request(optionspostjira, function(resjira) {
 console.log("statusCode: ", resjira.statusCode);
 // uncomment it for header details
console.log("headers: ", resjira.headers);

 resjira.on('data', function(d1) {
     console.info('PUT result:\n');
     process.stdout.write(d1);
     console.info('\n\PUT completed via NodeJS');
 });
});

console.log("JSON: ", jsonObjectJira);
//write the json data
reqPostJira.write(jsonObjectJira);
reqPostJira.end();
reqPostJira.on('error', function(e) {
 console.error(e);
});

})

enter code here
```

The same call works fine from POSTMAN with the same headers. Is there apparent thing which is wrong here?

Comment: Try logging the response body - in case of client errors (status 400) it will often contain more details on what's wrong.

Comment: Did you have settings saved in postman like username and password or access token?

Comment: Hi Yes I did, but it worked even after changing it.